# Sumifs with Vlookup/Index Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, sumifs

Is there a way I can do SUMIFS with Vlookup or Index function or anything I can use so I can do SUMIFS to Selected Agents on Table 2 from the reference Table 1?

[image]

From Table 2, I only want to do SUMIFS on Agent 9, 6, 5, 1 and 3 for the total of theirs Ys and Ns using the reference from Table 1, but for this I only want to SUMIF data range from January 1 to 4.

Comment: so you want the numbers in L and M respectively? I assume you already are doing the line by line SUMIFS?

Comment: I actually do but I also wanted to learn how I can SUMIFS based on date range like from Jan 1 to 4 only and not the whole week to date. And Yes, I can only do SUMIFS line by line like from Table 1, and since I have set of different lookup value like on Table 2, I wanted to do SUMIFS without doing line by line, and do this with INDEX or VLOOKUP.

Comment: Any other function will do as long as it is not SUMIFS line by line

Comment: That is going to get convoluted because of the merged cells. And you will want to split the start date and end date into two cells.

Comment: I can add a helper ROW on top of the dates and fill these cells that is equal = to the below dates and use this ROW as my criteria for my sum range

Comment: Then is is just a matter of using `INDEX($B$5:$K$14,MATCH($P5,$A$5:$A$14,0),0)` as your range to summed in the SUMIFS and setting the other criteria based on the date and `Y` or `N`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Excel 365, you can use

```
=SUMIF($B$5:$G$5,"Y",XLOOKUP(Q7,$A$5:$A$15,$B$5:$G$15))
```

This range formula from 1 - 4 & "Y" only.

If you want more range you can adjust the column on the table formula. Change column " $B$5:$G$5 "

[image: Excel screenshot showing solution]